# CKAN harvester 'nav_named_link' error

Tags: ckan, data-harvest

In CKAN, when I try to create a new Harvest Source I get this error:

```
Error - <class 'jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError'>: 'ckan.lib.helpers.HelperAttributeDict object' has no attribute 'nav_named_link
URL: https://127.0.0.1:5000/harvest/new
```

Does anybody know how I can fix this?

I'm new to CKAN. I installed from source and I also installed the ckanext-harvest extension.

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug. I supplied a fix: https://github.com/ckan/ckanext-harvest/pull/235 and now it has been merged you can simply update your copy of ckanext-harvest using `git pull`.

The `nav_named_link` helper was deprecated for a few years and I believe it finally got removed two weeks ago with [this pull](https://github.com/ckan/ckan/pull/2908).